# How to create helper in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, helper

I just created file `/CodeIgniter/application/helpers/ajax_helper.php` and now want to use it's functions in `CodeIgniter/application/controllers/Ajax.php` so i use:

```
function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    if((bool)$this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
        $this->load->helper('ajax');
    else
        return FALSE;
}
```

But error occurred:

> Unable to load the requested file: helpers/ajax_helper.php

What is wrong?

Comment: I had problems in the past loading them from my constructor so i just moved them to the controllers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use "MY_" prefix when CodeIgniter has built-in same-name helper (ajax_helper).
Please change the file name "my_ajax_helper.php" into "ajax_helper.php" and use `$this->load->helper('ajax');`

The "MY_" prefix is **only** use to extend CI's built-in core helper (same rule on controller, model, etc.),
for example, you can extend url_helper with my_url_helper, and load it by `$this->load->helper('url');`, not `'my_url'`, but you cannot create you own helper with this prefix.

**Update:**
Oops, sorry I found my answer maybe is wrong, CI could load custom helper with 'my_ajax' in my test. Maybe another probably reason is the file / folder permission?

**Update:** I checked CI's code and found it only output this message when file_exists() is return false, it means helper file not exists. So problem maybe cause by the file name, path, or letter case of ajax_helper.php.

Comment: sorry for my mistake - `MY` was added only for test. By default i tried without my and that error occurred.

Comment: Have you try to change the file / folder permission? Maybe the CI core have no permission to get the file. Test it use PHP's [is_readable()]
(http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-readable.php)

Comment: I have check the code of CI core, this error message is output when helper file not exist, maybe you can check if there is any typo?

Comment: there is chmod 777 to full folder.

Comment: Please re-check the file name, path, or letter case of `ajax_helper.php` because I found CI only output this message when `file_exists()` is return false (it means helper file not exists)

Comment: Problem was in config - i deleted `MY_`. There was just a `$config['subclass_prefix'] = '';`. Very strange behavior of framework

Answer (score 0):

The helper "ajax" doesn't exist in system of codeigniter, so first you can rename your filename like `ajax_helper.php`, second use :

```
 function __construct(){
parent::__construct();
if((bool)$this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
    $this->load->helper('ajax_helper');

else
    return FALSE;
}
```